# Mysql error for some reason?

Tags: mysql, sql

sorry about the last question. Puush was down! ANyways, here:

> [25/08/2013 00:07:50][DB LIB] Got exception @ MySQL_Connection::RunQuery(INSERT INTO characters (accountid, name, world, level, exp, str, dex, int, luk, hp, maxhp, mp, maxmp, meso, hpApUsed, job, skincolor, gender, fame, hair, face, faceMarking, ap, map, spawnpoint) VALUES (1,xenn,0,1,0,4,4,4,4,50,50,50,50,0,0,3002,1,0,0,36473,20185,1012363,0,0,0)) : MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int, luk, hp, maxhp, mp, maxmp, meso, hpApUsed, job, skincolor, gender, fame, ha' at line 1

Why am I getting an error? Thanks!

Comment: You need to post you original question here. Where is your code?

Answer (score 2):

`INT` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). You'll will need to wrap it in ticks.

```
INSERT INTO characters (accountid, name, world, level, exp, str, dex, `int`, luk, hp, maxhp, mp, maxmp, meso, hpApUsed, job, skincolor, gender, fame, hair, face, faceMarking, ap, map, spawnpoint) 
VALUES (1,xenn,0,1,0,4,4,4,4,50,50,50,50,0,0,3002,1,0,0,36473,20185,1012363,0,0,0)
```

Comment: or avoid it altogether

Comment: @Strawberry Some games including the one I'm developing this emulator for have int as short for Intellect.